# How do you map or alias a local path to a drive letter in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I"m trying to map a local path to, say the G: drive letter so I can access that path using G:.

E.g.,  something like g:\  ->   c:\some Dir\

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doesn't `subst G: C:\Some Dir` work any more in Win8?

Of course, you should be able to accomplish the same via Win Explorer as well:

[image]

[image]

But this works only in case of a Network Path and not a Local one.

Answer (score 6):

You will first need to share the folder, then you can map it in explorer as in Karan's answer or use

```
net use Z: \\yourpcname\foldername
```

Answer (score 6):

you need use vSubst utility to acheive the same.

download vSubst utility from below URL :
http://home.datacomm.ch/t.bigler/s04.html)

Comment: Working well on win10

Comment: vSubst is great - very small too 16kb!. My VM only has a C drive but I needed to deploy a BizTalk application with bindings that pointed at the D drive. I was able to run "vsubst d: c:\" - perfect :)

Comment: Still working well  :-)

Comment: What advantage does vSubst have over subst?